# Why does PDF file as blob open not work on localhost?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, pdf, blob

I have a vue app. I'm getting file from the server as a binary. I'm converting it to a blob and presenting in a new window tab as PDF. On the production it works fine but on local machine it says "Error couldn't load PDF-document". This is how I get and try to present the file:

```
async getFullReportAndRedirect() {
     try {
         const result = await apiService.getPdf();
         const newBlob = new Blob([result], {type: "application/pdf"})
         if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
             window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob);
             return;
         } 
         const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
         let link = document.createElement('a');
         link.href = data;
         link.target= '_blank';
         link.click();
         setTimeout(function(){
           // For Firefox
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
         }, 100);
     } catch(err) {
         console.log(err);
     }
}
```

So something like this `blob:http://localhost:8080/463d7877-8f9b-4136-9771-f7326dd62eab`doesn't work.
But on production this `blob:http://production-web/463d7877-8f9b-4136-9771-f7326dd62eab` works.

Comment: You are sure you get a PDF `apiService.getPdf()`? If so there may be an issue with vue routing.

Comment: @Tom-OliverHeidel yes, I'm sure. It gets binary response and everything works correctly on the production.